# eureka: how to register existing servers

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I am using a spring-cloud discovery service in my docker-compose. All spring-boot services that are under my control register themselves on startup via "EnableDiscoveryClient".

But I have other services in my docker-compose that I run from their dockerhub images. How can I register them as well (database, ldap, ...)
Is there a way to configure eureka to look for defined components (pull) instead of the client "push"?

Comment: Nothing by default. You could use the http api. netflix uses sidecars for certain situations.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to implement a `Sidecar` app and most-likely create a `Docker` image using a database, ldap image from the dockerhub as the starting point.

I published a blog post about this exact topic: [Microservices Sidecar pattern implementation using Postgres, Spring Cloud Netflix and Docker](http://tech.asimio.net/2018/02/20/Microservices-Sidecar-pattern-implementation-using-Postgres-Spring-Cloud-Netflix-and-Docker.html)